# Nuxt js styling issue

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I recently joined a team working on a nuxt js frontend application. Since the beginning, I could not make the project run properly in terms of styling.
Styles, classes, are correctly loaded in the html, I can clearly see them in the code inspector.
Though, it does not behave like it normally should (See picture 1). I compared nearly everything with the other developers and impossible to find a fix.

Did any of you already have such an issue ? And any idea of how to fix it ?

Thank you

[Small example of the styling issue I have between 2 menus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3tdM.jpg)

Comment: what is your `viewport` values in the `head.meta`? Is it different from the other developers'?

Comment: No, the same :/

Comment: not sure to guess what exactly is happening unless we see the code